# Netty - Increase Worker Thread count with only one open socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, netty

Im using Netty to implement my client/server architecture. The situation is the following:
1. Only 1 socket/connection is opened from 1 Client to the server
2. I create the bossgroup with 1 thread and the workergroup with 3 threads and assign them to the serverbootstrap.

Now when i monitor the cpu/threads with htop i only see 2 threads running on the server (probably 1 boss and 1 worker thread), but normally it should be 1 boss and 3 worker threads. Why do these worker threads don't get created?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Netty 3 ( it sounds like this), the threads will be lazy created and as you only have one connection there is no need to create another thread.

Comment: Hey Norman thank you for your answer. I am developing a protocol where a connection between two servers (A and B) gets created over one socket only. The server A opens the socket with a client bootstrap to the sever B and holds that socket open. Real clients now connect to server A and send their messages. Server A now acts like a proxy and sends all client messages with an id which is held in a hashmap to server B. Server B now only creates one thread to handle all messages. It doesn't matter how much threads i put into the Eventgroup only one thread is executed to take care

Comment: of the incoming messages because Netty assumes that the ordering of the whole income has to be the same but in reality the data consists of more messages

Comment: Server B has to do encryption work, as follows one core of the CPU is fully loaded and the others sleep. I need a way to give the encryption handler more threads but seems this is not possible with only one socket

Comment: And i use Netty 4.0.29

Comment: I tried to give the handler a DefaultEventExecutorGroup, still only 2 threads running the boss and worker thread for the single socket. In comparison i also implemented a version where multiple sockets (for each real client) between server A and B get created. With this multiple socket solution i reach the maximum CPU power with all threads executed specified in the workergroup for the bootstrap.

Comment: I solved the problem now by using java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) to create my own Thread Pool for the ciphering work. Everytime channelRead of the handler is called i use a thread of the pool to run the ciphering task. When the ciphering work is done for one client message, i write and flush it. I hope this is correct, so far i dont get any errors.